# How to consume SalesForce webservice from SSIS?

Tags: ssis, salesforce

I'm quite new to SalesForce and don't have much idea about it. I need to create a webservice in SalesForce and consume it from SSIS. If anyone can help me with a step by step process how to do it that would be very helpful for me.

Comment: Did you try to google first? Saw [this article](http://geekswithblogs.net/dataintegration/archive/2012/04/26/connect-salesforce-to-sql-server-through-ssis.aspx)?

Comment: For creating the web service what about this https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008xWbIAI  or this https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_web_services_methods.htm or this https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts